# How to store the current date and time when an event has occured

Tags: javascript, date, time

I currently want to make a contact manager application and I need to get the current time and date the user creates a new contact. The problem is that I am not able to find a way to store the current time and date the user created the contact. I tried getting the current time and date and converting it to JSON but it updates itself to the current time now, of which I do not want, I instead want to get the current time the user made the contact and store that current time. How can I achieve this using **pure Javascript**.

Try runing this code the first time, then refresh the browser and you will see the time changes.So it does not store the time because it gets somehow updated how can I solve this.

HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="btn" onclick="clicked()">Click me</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
const date = new Date();

function clicked() {
   localStorage.setItem("currentDate", JSON.stringify(date));
   var getDate = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentDate"));
    document.body.innerHTML += getDate;
}
```

Comment: `const currentTime = new Date();`

Comment: @ScottMarcus that does not store the current date and time. I need to get the current date and time and store it. Your code just gives me the current date but does not store it.

Comment: It does store it. It stores it in a variable. You should define what you mean by "store". How long do you want to "store" it?

Comment: I would like to store it like what local storage does. Storing that current date and time when the user makes a new contact for a long time(forever). So when the user checks for a contact they can see the date and time they made that contact.

Comment: So store it in localStorage. Do this at the moment the new contact is created:  `localStorage.setItem("currentDate", JSON.stringify(new Date());`

Comment: Yes when I do that its stores the date and time the user made the contact, but the problem is when the page is reloaded it updates its value to the current date and time **now** instead of showing me the date and time the contact was made.Try It

Comment: There's no reason it would do that if you extract the information with `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentDate"))` Whatever that date (represented as a string in localStorage) is will be converted back to a Date object. It will not adjust the date.

Comment: You also need to be making UNIQUE entries into `localStorage` for each contact, otherwise the situation you describe will happen.

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: See the new edit I made and test it

Comment: You don't need to use JSON at all. Rather than `JSON.stringify(new Date())`, use `new Date().toISOString()`, which is more efficient and semantic. `JSON.parse(string)` just returns the string, it isn't recognised as a Date, so just `var getDate = localStorage.getItem("currentDate")` is again, much more efficient and semantic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you click the button it will set a new date and time.

What you will want to do is GET the saved date on load. I created a function getDate that is called on page load as well as on click. If you don't want the date repeated after each click, then you will want to add a div in your HTML and replace it's content via:

```
document.querySelector("#timediv").innerHTML = theDate;
```

Below is the update javascript functions

```
function getDate(){
   var theDate = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentDate") || "[]");
   document.body.innerHTML += theDate + "<br>";
}    

 function clicked() {
   if (!localStorage.getItem("currentDate")) {
     localStorage.setItem("currentDate", JSON.stringify(new Date()));
   }
   
   getDate();
 }
```

Comment: When I click the button each time it gives me an updated time(the time write now). What I want is when I click the button it returns the same time instead of updating itself. So I want it to store the current time and date when the button was clicked and display that time and date the button was clicked. How can I do this?

Comment: Thanks alot I have been trying to get the solution for hours.